# List Gets Duplicated After Restarting (Saving To SharedPreferences And Getting It)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the following code:

```
public final class SharedPreferencesTools {
    private static final String USER_SETTINGS_PREFERENCES_NAME = "UserSettings";
    private static final String ALL_ITEMS_LIST = "AllItemsList";
    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static List<Item> getOrderedItems(Context context) {
        String stringValue = getUserSettings(context).getString(ALL_ITEMS_LIST, "");
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Item>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<Item> result = gson.fromJson(stringValue, collectionType);
        return (result == null) ? new ArrayList<Item>() : result;
    }

    public static void setOrderedItems(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        String stringValue = gson.toJson(items);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getUserSettings(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(ALL_ITEMS_LIST, stringValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    static SharedPreferences getUserSettings(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(USER_SETTINGS_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I get the items using SharedPreferenceTools.getOrderetedItems(this), it returns the normal list, but when I save it, it saves the list and add the original list, for example:

List A (Original) contains Steve, Frank, Alex.

I've opened the app and switched Frank position to Steve Position, And saved it using "setOrderedItems".

Now, Re-opened the app and got the following:

Frank, Steve, Alex (Modified) and Steve, Frank, Alex (Original), the original gets duplicated.

I'm getting and setting via the following way :

```
List<Item> List = SharedPreferencesTools.getOrderedItems(this); 
//List.add(new Item ...blabla) 
SharedPreferencesTools.setOrderedItems(this, List );
return List ;
```

**Log:**

I've added Log to get the length of "stringValue " inside Get and Set methods, Here's the log :

First run :

> Set: 1084
>
> Get: 0

Second Run :

> Set : 2167
>
> Get : 1084

Third run will be duplicated .

Comment: Duplicated where? what are you doing with the list? see it duplicated while debugging?

Comment: I've enabled Drag n Drop via ItemTouchHelper, I Wanted to save the positions when changed, So I'm using this code, When i drag anything and drop it and restart the app, the list gets duplicated .

Comment: You should paste here the code that calls the save method ... it maybe a problem there. also, try to log the items length when entering setOrderedItems and when exiting getOrderedItems to better understand where the problem may be...

Comment: Edited, Please check .

Comment: If you do the same process again do you end up with essentially 3 lists? It looks like you're not replacing the existing saved list but adding your new ordered list to it.

Comment: in your example you are calling getOrderedItems, then adding items to the same list you got as a return value and then saving it again ...

Comment: Yes, That what is happening, Every time i re-open the app, the list gets duplicated again and again, And i don't know why it's adding a new list, even though the code is right .

Comment: I don't see where you are actually manipulating the list... if you're using `list.add` like where it's commented out then that's just adding to the existing list.

Comment: Hmm, I'm gonna try to add "First Run" boolean, And check if it's getting duplicated, maybe that's why it's getting duplicated.

Comment: Ok, It's working, But the items that i added are "Toggles" their drawables, and color change according to the status, for example : If WiFi is on, or off, the WiFi toggle change according to it, the problem now is it's not changing according to the status, Even if i click it, it will change, but it will revert back to the old status when i re-open the app, How to solve that? .

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* **Clear your List** before setting it.

Replace:

```
List<Item> List = SharedPreferencesTools.getOrderedItems(this);
```

With:

```
ArrayList<Item> List = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should also avoid setting a variable name as List since it is a reserved name for the [List class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

---

*Original answer:*

**Clear** the key value before saving it with `editor.remove(String key)`.

---

*Example.*

Using your `setOrderedItems()` method:

```
public static void setOrderedItems(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        String stringValue = gson.toJson(items);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getUserSettings(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.remove(ALL_ITEMS_LIST); //Clearing previous value
        editor.putString(ALL_ITEMS_LIST, stringValue);
        editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: @AboHani Edited the answer --try creating a new List instead of retrieving the old one--

Comment: Mate, this code isn't going to solve the problem, Plus it won't save the current status, I've tried it, The problem is caused by "List.Add" after getting the saved list, that's why it's getting duplicated, But i'm having another problem ,if you please check the above comments.